# Function that which takes a list of strings and capitalizes them appropriately as a book or movie title (Check body for more info)

Tags: python, list, function

Specifically, the first word should always be capitalized, any word whose length is at least 4 should also be capitalized, and the other words should be in lowercase. For example, `title(['tHe', 'souND', 'AND', 'the', 'fUrY'])` returns `['The', 'Sound', 'and', 'the', 'Fury'].` You may assume that each string in the list contains only characters representing English letters. I have to do this function with my current method calling other helper functions to do it. And can only use map, reduce, list, filter, lambda.

Currently my code is:

```
def title(l):
    return [capitalize(l[0])] + (list(map(lambda x: capitalize if len(x) >= 4 else allLower, l[1:])))
print(title(['tHe', 'souND', 'AND', 'the', 'fUrY']))
```

The functions im calling in this one I refer to as my helper functions, which are made up of more helper functions. Refer to the code below:

```
def toUpper(c):
    o = ord(c)
    if o >= 97:
        return chr(o - 32)
    else:
        return c  #: Finished


def toLower(c):
    o = ord(c)
    if o <= 90:
        return chr(o + 32)
    else:
        return c  #: Finished


def allLower(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(toLower, s))

print(allLower('HELLO'))


def capitalize(s):
   return toUpper(s[0]) + reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(toLower, s[1:]))
print(capitalize("hello"))
```

Currently my title function is returning when it should be returning what the example shows (refer to the beginning text of this question):

```
['The', <function capitalize at 0x000002460A48EB80>, <function allLower at 0x000002460A48E700>, <function allLower at 0x000002460A48E700>, <function capitalize at 0x000002460A48EB80>]
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda x: capitalize`, you need `lamba x: capitalize(x)`.  Same with "allower".  A `lambda` should return a value, not a function.  By the way, are you aware that Python strings already offer all three of the functions you are writing here?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes I am aware, but I have criteria I have to follow for my class. Also this solved my problem thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something simple like:

```
def wordCasing(word):
    return word.capitalize() if len(word)>3 else word.lower()

title = ['tHe', 'souND', 'AND', 'the', 'fUrY']
result = list(map(wordCasing, title))
result[0] =result[0].capitalize()
print (result)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I would try and do something simpler, but I have to follow certain criteria. But for future reference I will note this.